# Python log into https website (epex spot) using requests to download files

Tags: python, python-requests, autologin

I trying to log into these website:
https://www.epexspot.com/en/extras/EPEXme/login using the requests method of Python. I tried the following code but as I am really new to this it is quite hard for me to get the relevant header information from the website.

```
from requests import session

payload = {
'text': 'username',
'password': 'password',
'logon': 'username',
'submit': 'Login'
}

headers = {
'Referer': 'https://www.epexspot.com/en/extras/EPEXme/login/login/
 aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZXBleHNwb3QuY29tL2VuL21hcmtldC1kYXRhL2hpc3RvcmljYWwtZGF0YS9
 yZXRyaWV2ZS9hdWN0aW9uX19nZXJtYW55X2F1c3RyaWEvYXVjdGlvbl9zcG90X3
 ByaWNlc19nZXJtYW55X2F1c3RyaWFfMjAxNC5jc3Y%3D'
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0'
}

with session() as c:
c.post('link', data=payload, verify=False, headers=headers)
request = c.get('https://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/historical-data/retrieve
_auction_germany_austria/auction_spot_prices_germany_austria_2014.csv, verify=False)
request.content
```

However, request.content gives me the information of the login website and not the content I would like to have.
As mentionened above I am really new to this login stuf. I read a lot here but I guess my main problem is how to understand and identify the components I need to extract from the website (headers, payload). 
I knew that there might be other tools to do the same job but my main target is to understand these basics.

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the HTML source code of the page's login `<form>`, which is on lines 267 to 292.

You need to submit the payload data to the URL in the form's `action` attribute: "https://www.epexspot.com/en/extras/EPEXme/login/User/show_login_form".

The payload data will consist of the names and values for the various `<form>` data elements (generally `<input>` elements but sometimes also other things like `<textarea>`), including any hidden elements. The relevant elements for this page are named:

"User-show_login_form[form][login][page1][page_values][page_sent]"

"User-show_login_form[form][login][page1][login][]"

"User-show_login_form[form][login][page1][password][]"

Disclaimer: I've never done this sort of thing using Requests (last time I did it was a few years ago, using urllib2), so hopefully someone else will give more details.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, tried it but without success. Do you know what I have to put here:   "User-show_login_form[form][login][page1][page_values][page_sent]"

Comment: That's the name of the `hidden` input element on line 269, which has a constant value of "1". On trickier forms, hidden fields may be modified by client-side JavaScript, but we don't have to worry about that here. I haven't looked closely at all the HTML source of that page, but hopefully we only need to focus on the source code of the login form itself. But as I mentioned in my answer I'm a bit out of practice with this sort of stuff, and there may be something important that I'm forgetting.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! I put the "1" and eliminated one typing error.